# Before using it, the plugin has to be configured. Please do so from the system configuration

Tags: java, jenkins, weblogic

Im use jenkins weblogic plugin, when I config job it says:

```
Before using it, the plugin has to be configured. 
Please do so from the system configuration
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

but I hava config plugin in system config

Answer (score 0):

The [Weblogic Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin) shows the following system configuration (in the Jenkins system config page)

[image]

In particular, you need to set the **Configuration File**:

> xml file path containing deployments targets.
>   It has to be [http://host:port/plugin/weblogic-deployer-plugin/defaultConfig/plugin-configuration.xsd] schema compliant. No validation currently performed.
>
> The file can be added through a local path (`/usr/users/.../plugin-configuration.xml`) or a remote URL (http://xxxxxxxxx/plugin-configuration.xml);

Comment: @user5840261 THen your configuration path might not be correct, or its content might not follow the plugin-configuration.xsd schema.